# Compiling ffmpeg for use in Android (ndk) for x86 architecture

Tags: compilation, android-ndk, ffmpeg, intel

I am trying to compile ffmpeg for Android but for the x86 architecture. I've successfully compiled an arm .so and it all works, and I though that by replacing arm with x86 in the relevant places within the build script would have done the trick. Unfortunately that's not the case and I get some strange things occurring.

First I get this while it's compiling ffmpeg:

```
/home/ankur/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-arm//usr/include/strings.h:49: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'index'
```

Notice the arch-arm instead of arch-x86. Finally I get this:

```
/home/ankur/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-ld: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(4xm.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/ankur/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-ld: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(4xm.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/ankur/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-ld: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(4xm.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(4xm.o): could not read symbols: File in wrong format
```

The build script I've created looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=~/android-ndk-r8
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-x86/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
function build_one_r8
{
./configure \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-version3 \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-postproc \
    --enable-small \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/i686-android-linux- \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --target-os=linux \
    --extra-cflags="-I$PLATFORM/usr/include" \
    --arch=x86 \
    --disable-symver \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-stripping \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
sed -i 's/HAVE_LRINT 0/HAVE_LRINT 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_LRINTF 0/HAVE_LRINTF 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_ROUND 0/HAVE_ROUND 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_ROUNDF 0/HAVE_ROUNDF 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_TRUNC 0/HAVE_TRUNC 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_TRUNCF 0/HAVE_TRUNCF 1/g' config.h
make clean
make  -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/i686-android-linux-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/i686-android-linux-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}
function build_one_r8_2
{
$PREBUILT/bin/i686-android-linux-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/i686-android-linux-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}
#x86
CPU=x86
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one_r8
```

I hope I'm doing something wrong rather than this not being possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to compile for the Atom, BUT the GoogleTV has no support for the NDK, which explains why all my attempts of compiling NDK for my GoogleTV device have not work. I hope it's coming soon!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my build script, if it's helpful, I see a few things I have set that you don't seem to which may be part of your problem. I source it from on directory below the ffmpeg source dir (source). I.E. the script is called build.sh and resides in ~/android/ffmpeg, the ffmpeg source is in ~/android/ffmpeg/source and my build output ends up in ~/android/build/armeabi-v7a when I run the script as such:

```
~/android/ffmpeg$ source build.sh
```

This is build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=~/android/ndk
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
ABI="armeabi-v7a"
CPU="armv7-a"
ARCH="arm"
FPU="vfpv3-d16"
ANDROID_LIBS=$SYSROOT/usr/lib
DEST="../build/ffmpeg/$ABI"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L$ANDROID_LIBS -Wl,-rpath-link,$ANDROID_LIBS"
EXTRA_CXXFLAGS="-Wno-multichar -Wno-psabi -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"
EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DANDROID -marm -march=$CPU -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=$FPU"

function configure
{
./configure \
    --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$DEST \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" \
    --extra-cxxflags="$EXTRA_CXXFLAGS" \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=$ARCH \
    --cpu=$CPU \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-optimizations \
    --disable-neon \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-armv5te \
    --disable-armv6 \
    --disable-armv6t2 \
    --disable-armvfp \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-protocols \
    --disable-indevs \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-outdevs \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-swresample \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-swscale-alpha \
    --disable-avresample \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-pthreads \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-libvpx \
    --enable-decoder=vp8 \
    --enable-parser=vp8 \
    --enable-demuxer=matroska
}
cd source
make clean &&
configure &&
make -j8 && 
rm -rf $DEST &&
mkdir -p $DEST &&
make install
```

Comment: Thanks, Justin

I found out that Google TV doesn't support NDK! Thanks for the script though, it may come in use sometime soon.